# VMM Error: 1604 Cannot Access Virtual Machine Manager

Tags: authentication, scvmm

I keep getting the error:

```
You cannot access Virtual Machine Manager server localhost.

Cantact the Virtual Machine Manager administrator to verify that your account 
is a member of a valid user role and then try the operation again

ID: 1604
```

My setup:

- Win Server 2008 R2 (Domain Controller)
- Hyper-V installed
- System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2008 R2 installed

I am logged in under Domain\Administrator, yet it still says I have no access to VMM.

Administrator is a member of: Administrators/Domain Admins/Domain Users/Enterprise Admins/Group Policy Creator Owners/Schema Admins/Virtual Machine Manager Servers.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

ps. this is a test machine that I have set up to get familiar/learn about VMM and Hyper-V

Comment: Did you by any chance change the admin password because of all the root cause mine is caused due to this as there is no other way to explain it